# How to boost results with recent date using SOLR

Tags: solr

Here is what I'm seeing with no boost, just to show that my date field is present and stored:

[image]

Now here's what happens when I try to add a boost for `release_date_dts`:

[image]

I tried adding `!boost b=recip(ms(NOW,release_date_dts),3.16e-11,1,1)` to my `q` field but that led to no results.

I also tried adding `recip(ms(NOW,release_date_dts),3.16e-11,1,1)` to my edismax `bf` field, but that led to 0 results as well.

Comment: Is release_date_dts is a indexed field ??

Comment: which request handler are you using?

Comment: Here's the full URL, if that helps @JorgeLuis `http://localhost:8982/solr/development/select?q=!boost+b%3Drecip(ms(NOW%2Crelease_date_dts)%2C3.16e-11%2C1%2C1)&fq=type%3AHearingAid&wt=xml&indent=true`

Comment: Can you enable the debugQuery to see how is the score calculated and the query processed, also try checking the `edismax` checkbox to ensure that the right query handler is used.

Comment: Hey it seemed to word putting under `edismax` `bf` as shown `http://localhost:8982/solr/development/select?q=*%3A*&fq=type%3AHearingAid&wt=json&defType=edismax&bf=recip(ms(NOW%2Crelease_date_dts)%2C3.16e-11%2C1%2C1)&stopwords=true&lowercaseOperators=true`